# import jwt from swift cocoa touch framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, jwt

I am working on `swift cocoa touch framework` to create reusable framework from mobile application.

my framework need to use `jwt` project from `https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git`

i tried to create `Package.swift` and then add `.package(url:"https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", from: "3.0.0")` and then run `swift package resolve`

in my code, i import jwt library like this

```
import JWT
import Foundation
```

but i got the error `No such module 'JWT'`

i am newbie on swift, can someone help please?

my Package.swift is here

```
// swift-tools-version:4.2
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription

let package = Package(
    name: "edoc-sdk-swift",
    products: [
        // Products define the executables and libraries produced by a package, and make them visible to other packages.
        .library(
            name: "edoc-sdk-swift",
            targets: ["edoc-sdk-swift"]),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url:"https://github.com/vapor/jwt.git", from: "3.0.0")
    ],
    targets: [
        // Targets are the basic building blocks of a package. A target can define a module or a test suite.
        // Targets can depend on other targets in this package, and on products in packages which this package depends on.
        .target(
            name: "edoc-sdk-swift",
            dependencies: ["JWT"]),
        .testTarget(
            name: "edoc-sdk-swiftTests",
            dependencies: ["edoc-sdk-swift"]),
    ]
)
```

Comment: it does not work for both `jwt` or `JWT` @user28434

Comment: Download project from git and add this folder jwt/Sources/JWT/ to your project manually

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks all guys for the feedback.

now i can solve the problem, and i write the solution to this blog

https://piggyman007.blogspot.com/2018/12/create-swift-framework-and-include-some.html

Answer (score 0):

You should check two things:

1. Module name is [`JWT`, not `jwt`](https://github.com/vapor/jwt/blob/master/Package.swift).
2. Check that your `.target` in `Package.swift` contains `"JWT"` in `dependencies`

Comment: it does not work for both `jwt` or `JWT`,  i have added my Package.swift in the detail

Comment: I've just created new blank project names `edoc-sdk-swift` and used your `Package.swift` and It compiled. @AlongkornChetasumon

Comment: @AlongkornChetasumon, there was Xcode error in generated Xcode project though, but it disappeared right after first build.

Comment: can you try creating `cocoa touch framework` using xcode, and try to include this `JWT` please?